# Transit visa requirement for Zurich

Tags: visas, transit, canada, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I will travel from India to Canada via Zurich, I have a layover of 3 hr 45 minute in Zurich,
I have valid Canada immigrant visa,
I am an Indian citizen, I hold valid Indian passport.

Do I need transit visa for changing plane in Zurich? I will not go out from Zurich airport.